# $\arg(\overline{z}), \arg(z^2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms, multivalued-functions

[A First Course in Complex Analysis by Matthias Beck, Gerald Marchesi, Dennis Pixton, and Lucas Sabalka](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/complex.html) Exer 3.42,43

> [image]

Exer 3.42 multiple-valued: NO in general.

$$\arg(1+i)=\frac \pi 4 + 2k \pi$$
$$\arg(1-i)=\frac {-\pi} 4 - 2l \pi$$

Choose $k=1$,$l=17$ to arrive at a contradiction.

Exer 3.42 principal: NO, but YES iff $z \notin \mathbb R_{< 0}$

Pf:

$$Arg(\overline{z}) = -Arg(z) \iff -Arg(z) \in (-\pi,\pi] \iff Arg(z) \in [-\pi,\pi]) \iff Arg(z) \in (-\pi,\pi) \iff z \notin \mathbb R_{< 0}$$

QED

Exer 3.43 multiple-valued: NO in general.

For $z = 0$, yes vacuously. For $z \ne 0$,

Observe that $\ln|z^2| = \ln(|z|^2) = 2\ln|z|$

$$\therefore, \ln(z^2) = 2\ln(z) \iff \arg(z^2) = 2\arg(z)$$

Consider

$$\arg(1+i)=\frac \pi 4 + 2k \pi$$
$$\arg(2i) = \frac \pi 2 + 4l \pi$$

Choose $k=1$,$l=17$ to arrive at a contradiction.

Exer 3.43 single-valued: NO, but YES iff $Arg(z) \in (-\frac \pi 2,\frac \pi 2]$.

Pf:

For $z = 0$, yes vacuously. For $z \ne 0$,

Observe that $Ln|z^2| = Ln(|z|^2) = 2Ln|z|$

$$\therefore, Ln(z^2) = 2Ln(z) \iff Arg(z^2) = 2Arg(z)$$

$$Arg(z^2) = 2Arg(z) \iff 2Arg(z) \in (-\pi,\pi] \iff Arg(z) \in (-\frac \pi 2,\frac \pi 2]$$

QED

---

1. Where have I gone wrong for above solutions?
2. Which are wrong? I believe they're all right, but I might have missed something (For $z=0$, I guess the relevant statements are vacuously true).

$$\arg(\overline{z}) \equiv -\arg(z) \mod 2 \pi \ \forall z \in \mathbb R_{<0}$$

$$Arg(\overline{z}) \equiv -Arg(z) \mod 2 \pi \ \forall z \in \mathbb R_{<0}$$

$$\arg(\overline{z}) \equiv -\arg(z) \mod 2 \pi \ \forall z \notin \mathbb R_{<0}$$

$$Arg(\overline{z}) \equiv -Arg(z) \mod 2 \pi \ \forall z \notin \mathbb R_{<0}$$

$$\arg(z^2) \equiv 2\arg(z) \mod 2 \pi \ \forall z \in \mathbb R_{<0}$$

$$Arg(z^2) \equiv 2Arg(z) \mod 2 \pi \ \forall z \in \mathbb R_{<0}$$

$$\arg(z^2) \equiv 2\arg(z) \mod 2 \pi \ \forall z \notin \mathbb R_{<0}$$

$$Arg(z^2) \equiv 2Arg(z) \mod 2 \pi \ \forall z \notin \mathbb R_{<0}$$

It seems 2.6 and 2.8 are right by [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Identities). What about the others?

Answer (score 1):

(*Partial answer for* **3.42** *below,* **3.43** *can be worked out in a similar way*.)  The following assumes that $z \ne 0$ and $\arg(ab)=\arg(a)+\arg(b)$ was already established for the multi-valued $\arg$.

> Exer 3.42 multiple-valued: NO in general.

YES, in general, since $\arg(z\bar z) = \arg(z)+\arg(\bar z)$, but on the other hand $\arg(z \bar z) = \arg(|z|^2) = 0$ because $|z|^2$ is a positive real number, so $\,\arg(\bar z) = -\arg(z)\,$.

> $$\arg(1+i)=\frac \pi 4 + 2k \pi$$
>   $$\arg(1-i)=\frac {-\pi} 4 - 2l \pi$$
>   Choose $k=1$,$l=17$ to arrive at a contradiction.

You don't get to *choose* $k,l$ here. The multi-valued $\arg$ equality holds if there exists *any* pair $k,l$ for which it holds, in this case $k=l=0$ for example.

> Exer 3.42 principal: NO, but YES iff $z \notin \mathbb R_{< 0}$

It looks like this uses the (common) definition of the [principal value of $\operatorname{Arg}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Principal_value) where the range is $(-\pi,\pi]$. In that case the answer is YES, except if $\,\operatorname{Arg}(z)=\pi\,$ (*why?*).

If using the *other* (less common) definition for the principal value of $\operatorname{Arg}$ where the range is $[0,2 \pi)$ then the answer is of course NO, except if $\,\operatorname{Arg}(z)=0\,$ (*why?*).

Comment: dxiv, thanks. For Exer 3.42 multiple: How do you know 'if there exists any pair' ? Could this possibly differ by textbook? I think I saw Brown-Churchill have some discussion on $\arg(z_1z_2) = \arg(z_1) + \arg(z_2)$, but I'm not sure this textbook has. It doesn't even have de Moivre's formula which I had to deduce from Prop 1.3a. Anyhoo, may you please help me find? All I found is on p.4: '...has infinitely many possible arguments...1 = 1 + 0i lies on the positive real axis, and so has argument 0...or 2pk for any integer k.' I'm not sure there's a mention of equality of arguments outside exer.

Comment: 'For Exer 3.43 principal $Arg(z) = \pi \iff z \in \mathbb R_{<0}$ and $Arg(z) = 0 \iff z \in \mathbb R_{>0}$ Thanks for the info on the less common.

Comment: 'and $\arg(ab)=\arg(a)+\arg(b)$ was already established for the multi-valued $\arg$' --> It wasn't or at least not explicitly. May you please check for me? Or what textbook/s did you use when you first learned complex analysis?

Comment: @BCLC There *must* be a definition of $\arg$ somewhere in your textbook, if there are exercises about it. What is that definition? Most proofs of $\,\arg(ab)=\arg(a)+\arg(b)\,$ use the polar form indeed (e.g. [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Argument_of_Product_equals_Sum_of_Arguments)), but the relation can also be derived algebraically from the cartesian representation and the definition of the complex product (e.g. adapt [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2367685/proving-argument-of-complex-number-properties) proof for multiplication).

Comment: Had no idea texts could be so varied on this. I'll probably go to another such as Brown-Churchill for this. Thanks!

Comment: ah found it. It's on p.5-6. you could consider it explicit but it's mentioned in passing. I think they could've been more conspicuous or discussed in depth. What's your interpretation of the passage as it relates to Exer 3.42?

Comment: @BCLC I think the relevant definitions go back to p.4 for the multi-valued $\,\arg\,$ "and ***an*** *argument of z = x + iy is a number φ ∈ R such that...*" with the note on p.5 that "*the arguments of z all differ by a multiple of 2π*", then p.45 for the principal value $\,\operatorname{Arg}\,$. That said, the course is in complex *analysis*, and it looks written as if previous familiarity with complex *numbers* is assumed.

Comment: dxiv thanks. On last sentence: come on really? But all introductory complex analysis texts start with complex numbers right? It's like how introductory linear algebra texts begin with matrices whether or not some topics in matrices were taught in secondary school or in calculus?

Comment: Actually also note the wording of the question in Exer 3.42: It says 'What about'. Sounds to me like something you would say if you just asked a question and got a negative response. Or not really?

Answer (score 0):

problem 1

This is controversial problem, the answer depends on its definition.

[See also](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2452144/why-does-argz2-neq-2argz)

problem 2

take $z=re^{i\theta}$, 
$$\log z^2=2\log |z|+i(2\theta+2n\pi)$$, $$2\log z=2\log|z|+i(2\theta+4n\pi )$$

Thus $\log z^2$ contains $2\log z$.

Comment: Arigatou Takahiro Waki-san! Had no idea texts could be so varied on this. I'll probably go to another such as Brown-Churchill for this.